# Symlink problems with OSX dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, nautilus, macosx, symbolic-link

I'm having some problems with soft links that direct to files in a shared partition I'm using to share files between Ubuntu and OSX. When I first set everything up it all worked perfectly, but after a restart the links are coming up as broken.

I can get everything to work correctly again by going into the shared partition, opening one of the files that my symlinks point to (and, as far as I can tell, it has to contain something), and opening properties... provided that nautilus crashes when I do so. After that everything shows up completely normal until my next restart.

I'm not sure how to tell if it has something to do with the fact that the links are pointing to folders that OSX uses, or if there's just something about setting up symlinks pointing to a partition that I missed. (I just decided to play around with dual-boot file-sharing options after using a Ubuntu-only machine for many years, so I'm new to a lot of this) Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: A swap partition is used for swapping memory pages in and out of active memory. Perhaps this is the source of your problem. Such partitions are never used for storage.

Comment: It's just a regular partition-- I was just calling it that as more of a colloquial use of the word since it's the partition that I use to swap data back and forth between OSX and Ubuntu.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why nautilus crashes at the point you describe. I would start by looking at permissions on the sym-link and the target file (is there a discrepancy between the 2 systems?)